# Can't connect to web hosting with Filezilla - Shows Initializing TLS

Tags: sftp, ftp

I am trying to open my web hosting account using filezilla, but continuously failing to open it via Filezilla. It always gets timeout after saying `Initializing TLS...` My hosting provider are saying that they are able to login successfully!

I enabled debugging and logging in filezilla to get more details and here is the snippet of debug output:

```
00:06:44    Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
00:06:45    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
00:06:45    Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
00:06:45    Response:   220-You are user number 1 of 150 allowed.
00:06:45    Response:   220-Local time is now 18:36. Server port: 21.
00:06:45    Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
00:06:45    Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
00:06:45    Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 5 minutes of inactivity.
00:06:45    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
00:06:45    Command:    AUTH TLS
00:06:45    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
00:06:45    Response:   234 AUTH TLS OK.
00:06:45    Status: Initializing TLS...
00:06:45    Trace:  CTlsSocket::Handshake()
00:06:45    Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
00:06:45    Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnSend()
00:07:06    Error:  Connection timed out
00:07:06    Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(2050)
00:07:06    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
00:07:06    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
00:07:06    Error:  Could not connect to server
00:07:06    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(2114)
```

Can anybody can give me some insights on what's going wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're connecting to a FTPS server in active mode. When you're connecting to the server the server responds with an encrypted data channel. Since it's encrypted and you have no way of knowing what port it's coming in on, your firewall has no way of dynamically opening the port and just assumes it's an unknown attempt to communicate from the outside.

Try setting the connection to passive and see if that resolves it.

Comment: In filezilla, the connection is already set to `passive`. I even tried setting it to `active` - Both gives the same results!